# 'list' object has no attribute 'splitlines' Django send_email

Tags: python, django-views, django-email

I'm trying to send a mass email to all id's in the database

This is my code:

```
def email_sent(request):
    email_id_fans = models.email_id.email_address
    #print(email_id_fans)
    subject = "sub"
    email_text = models.send_email.objects.all()[0]
    lines = str(email_text).splitlines()
    message = lines
    email_from = settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER
    recipient_list = [email_id_fans, ]
    send_mail(subject, message, email_from, recipient_list)

    return HttpResponse()
```

This is the error i get:
'list' object has no attribute 'splitlines'

Comment: Did you redefine ``str`` somewhere in your code? Does ``lines = str(email_text).splitlines()`` trigger the error, or ``send_mail(subject, message, email_from, recipient_list)``?

Comment: Please show your models